# \tag{} causes line break in align environment. how to prevent?

Tags: line-breaking, amsmath, align

while using the `leqno` and `fleqn` options of `amsmath` package `tag`s tend to cause line-breaks:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[leqno, fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\cee{
MgO_{(s)} + 2HCl_{(aq)} &-> MgCl2_{(aq)} + H2O_{(l)} \tag{Exp 1}\\
 Mg_{(s)} + 2HCl_{(aq)} &-> MgCl2_{(aq)} + H2_{(g)} \tag{Exp 2}
}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

This prints:

[image]

How can I prevent this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if `\cee` is needed, it must be wrapped separately around the contents of each cell.  the way it is now, `align` will assume that the entire content of `\cee` is a single expression, and won't act properly on the `\\ ` or `&`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton that's not really true. `\cee` was designed to act properly on `&` and ` \\ ` in displayed math expressions. The problem here was that there was not enough space (which you can see if you remove `\cee` from the example code).

Comment: barbara is probably thinking of `\ce`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- that's a new one for me; of course, we don't handle much chemistry here, and the principle of "cell independence" has been beaten into my head for a long time (especially with respect to `\left` and `\right`).  thanks for the information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the math indent large enough for the tags:

[image]

```
\documentclass[leqno, fleqn]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\setlength\mathindent{3cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
MgO_{(s)} + 2HCl_{(aq)} &-> MgCl2_{(aq)} + H2O_{(l)} \tag{Exp 1}\\
 Mg_{(s)} + 2HCl_{(aq)} &-> MgCl2_{(aq)} + H2_{(g)} \tag{Exp 2}
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, however, `\setlength\mathindent{3cm}` indents all math environments. how do I localize it to just this one?

Comment: `\begin{setlength}\mathindent{3cm}

\end{setlength}`

seems to work. thanks.